# CSS element always on top

Tags: html, css

Is this possible to have element with class .myelement always on top in my HTML structure?

```
<div class="zindex1">
  <div class="myelement">
    want THIS element always be on top
  </div>
</div>
<div class="zindex2">
</div>
```

and with for example this CSS

```
.zindex1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.zindex2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.myelement {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

**NOTE:** I can't change values of my z-indexes and HTML structure.

Here is full example: https://jsfiddle.net/wLzej01f/

**EDIT** What if all my classes will have to have position: relative? I forget to mention about it
https://jsfiddle.net/wLzej01f/6/

Comment: **position:relative** to .myelement

Comment: read edit please

Comment: Change the index of zindex1 to 3, you can't make myelement be on top because zindex1 (his parent) is bottom zindex2

Comment: what you want to achieve ? and why all these restrictions ?

Comment: i want to have the element on top and these restricitons are beacause of architecture in my app that I can't change

Answer (score 2):

The `z-index` CSS property won't apply to static elements:

> For a positioned box (that is, **one with any position other than
>   static**), the z-index property specifies:
>
> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

More about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

So, you need to add:

```
.myelement {
    position: relative;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLzej01f/4/).

Comment: If you set the `z-index` to siblings, than browser will respect it. In your case you put `.zindex2` div over the `.zindex1` div - therefor **every child of `.zindex1` will be below `.zindex2`**. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Yes, I did it like you said, but it's still not working. https://jsfiddle.net/wLzej01f/7/

Comment: It won't work ever, because you put z-index to main containers and browser respects that. If you want `.myelement` to be above, than do not put `z-index` to parent sibling containers, ok?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is trying to keep an element in a fixed position on the rest of the elements or does not know why one element is below another, keep in mind the sticky element.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp

Answer (score 0):

Position: relative

```css
.zindex1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.zindex2 {
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  height: 300px;
}

.myelement {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="zindex1">
  <div class="myelement">
    want THIS element always be on top
  </div>
</div>
<div class="zindex2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add

```
position: absolute;
```

or

```
position: relative;
```

as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:relative` to `.myelement`:

```
.myelement {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wLzej01f/5/)

Answer (score -1):

```
.zindex1 {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

.zindex2 {
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}

.myelement {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2 !important;
}


**This code works**
```